How to debug "IndexError: string index out of range"
Good day! I've try to do the task for myself and had an error. when i want to compare numbers of symbols. Here my code:
h = int(input())
s = input()
k = 0
k_1 = 0
for i in range(0, h-1):
    if ord('A') <= ord(s[i]) <= ord('Z') and ord('A') <= ord(s[i+1]) <= ord('Z') and ord('A') <= ord(s[i+2]) <= ord('Z'):
        k_1 += 1
        while ord('A') <= ord(s[i]) <= ord('Z'):
            k = k + 1
            i = i + 1
    if ord('a') <= ord(s[i]) <= ord('z') and ord('a') <= ord(s[i+1]) <= ord('z') and ord('a') <= ord(s[i+2]) <= ord('z'):
        k_1 += 1
        while ord('a') <= ord(s[i]) <= ord('z'):
            k = k + 1
            i = i + 1
    if ord('A') <= ord(s[i]) <= ord('Z') and ord('A') <= ord(s[i+1]) <= ord('Z') and ord('a') <= ord(s[i+2]) <= ord('z'):
        k_1 += 2
        k += 2
        i += 2
        continue
    if ord('a') <= ord(s[i]) <= ord('z') and ord('a') <= ord(s[i+1]) <= ord('z') and ord('A') <= ord(s[i+2]) <= ord('Z'):
        k_1 += 2
        k += 2
        i += 2
        continue
    if ord('A') <= ord(s[i]) <= ord('Z') and ord('a') <= ord(s[i+1]) <= ord('z') and ord('a') <= ord(s[i+2]) <= ord('z'):
        k_1 += 1
        k += 1
        i += 1
        continue
    if ord('a') <= ord(s[i]) <= ord('z') and ord('A') <= ord(s[i+1]) <= ord('Z') and ord('A') <= ord(s[i+2]) <= ord('Z'):
        k_1 += 1
        k += 1
        i += 1
        continue
print(k + k_1)

Please write me your decisions. Thanks!
.........................

[Edit] your question to include the entire error message, including full stack trace.

Please give example values for h and s

If you want to know if a character is uppercase or lowercase, use s[i].isupper() or s[i].islower(), rather than comparing with A and Z.

The error "IndexError: string index out of range" is because the code is looping the counter (for example i) outside the expected range or allowed boundary.
I've made some changes to your code:

I used a while-loop for better control, because using i within the for-loop will need me to always calculate that it is within range. While-loop is easier to stay within the allowed boundary.
I adjusted increment to skip checked characters, to reduce redundant steps

See if it works for you:
h = int(input())
s = input()
k = 0
k_1 = 0
i = 0    #Changed from for loop to while loop for better control

while i < h - 2:    #Ensure we don't go out of bounds
    if ord('A') <= ord(s[i]) <= ord('Z') and ord('A') <= ord(s[i+1]) <= ord('Z') and ord('A') <= ord(s[i+2]) <= ord('Z'):
        k_1 += 1
        while i < h and ord('A') <= ord(s[i]) <= ord('Z'):    #Added boundary check
            k += 1
            i += 1
    elif ord('a') <= ord(s[i]) <= ord('z') and ord('a') <= ord(s[i+1]) <= ord('z') and ord('a') <= ord(s[i+2]) <= ord('z'):
        k_1 += 1
        while i < h and ord('a') <= ord(s[i]) <= ord('z'):    #Added boundary check
            k += 1
            i += 1
    elif ord('A') <= ord(s[i]) <= ord('Z') and ord('A') <= ord(s[i+1]) <= ord('Z') and ord('a') <= ord(s[i+2]) <= ord('z'):
        k_1 += 2
        k += 2
        i += 3    #Adjusted increment to skip checked characters
    elif ord('a') <= ord(s[i]) <= ord('z') and ord('a') <= ord(s[i+1]) <= ord('z') and ord('A') <= ord(s[i+2]) <= ord('Z'):
        k_1 += 2
        k += 2
        i += 3    #Adjusted increment to skip checked characters
    elif ord('A') <= ord(s[i]) <= ord('Z') and ord('a') <= ord(s[i+1]) <= ord('z') and ord('a') <= ord(s[i+2]) <= ord('z'):
        k_1 += 1
        k += 1
        i += 2    #Adjusted increment to skip checked characters
    elif ord('a') <= ord(s[i]) <= ord('z') and ord('A') <= ord(s[i+1]) <= ord('Z') and ord('A') <= ord(s[i+2]) <= ord('Z'):
        k_1 += 1
        k += 1
        i += 2    #Adjusted increment to skip checked characters
    else:
        i += 1    #Ensure we move to the next character if no condition is met

print(k + k_1)

